# Cardview suddenly stops showing shadow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, out-of-memory

How to show **cardview elevation** if

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml**

My Application config is

```
    <application
    android:name="MyappApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

and my CardView is

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_small"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_small"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to cast shadows with 
 `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`. If it is strictly necessary in your app, one solution could be setting the acceleration by activities instead of application level.

`<activity ... />
  <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="" />`

This way you could leave as `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` the activities where cardviews are not being used and the application level tag as true.

Comment: if I remove from application label, app closes itself without throwing any error..

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try to set the application android:hardwareAccelerated as true and the activities where cardviews are not being used as false.

Comment: I tried android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in application label and android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in activitties where cardviews are being used. and that works for me. thanks bro :)

Comment: nice! I'm Glad it helped you.